# Why does script file that's loaded before jQuery still work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, loading, waterfall

I am planning to load jQuery over a CDN from a Rails app. Unfortunately I am unable show the code, but I'll try to explain. The code was set up as follows:

in layout, before closing body tag:

```
= javascript_include_tag "main_web"
```

main_web.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require page_script
```

Now what I want to do, is

in layout

```
= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"
= javascript_include_tag "main_web"
```

and in main_web.js I would remove the jQuery dependency

```
//=require page_script
```

I did that and now I have a waterfall that looks like this:

[image: waterfall]

I want to be sure that when I implement that change, that none of my visitors' browsers will try to execute the main_script before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: You should show the code, but it probably has a wrapper that prevents immediate execution.

Comment: why wouldn't it work? You haven't mentioned any problem or errors that would indicate otherwise. Really not clear what your issue is

Comment: You need to show the HTML of your entire output page. There are too many unknowns at the moment. Voting to close.

Comment: I am sorry about confusing wording. I rewrote the question and hope you'll get a better picture now.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure of where your scripts are or how they are rendered on the page but JavaScript files loaded from markup are executed sequentially. Therefore if you have two script files in your page:

```
<script src="filea.js"></script>
<script src="fileb.js"></script>
```

filea.js will execute before fileb.js

This situation could be occurring in your example but without knowing how they are loaded I cannot be sure.